# Set title for Java window when running tomcat

Tags: java, cmd

I'm writing a script to start up several tomcat servers, like so

```
cd "F:\...\apache-tomcat-5.5.33\bin"
call "cmd /c startup.bat"
cd "F:\...\apache-tomcat-5.5.33\bin"
call "cmd /c startup.bat"
etc
```

which I have working but each one opens in a java window that just says 'tomcat' at the top.  Is it possible for me to specify what this text says?  I'd really like to be able to tell them all apart!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to set an environment variable. Read the last one that says `TITLE`. I found this inside `catalina.bat`.

```
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Start/Stop Script for the CATALINA Server
rem
rem Environment Variable Prerequisites
rem
rem   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
rem   setenv.bat in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
rem
rem   CATALINA_HOME   May point at your Catalina "build" directory.
rem
rem   CATALINA_BASE   (Optional) Base directory for resolving dynamic portions
rem                   of a Catalina installation.  If not present, resolves to
rem                   the same directory that CATALINA_HOME points to.
rem
rem   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
rem                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
rem                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
rem                   only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
rem                   the version command etc.
rem                   Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.
rem
rem   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
rem                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
rem                   %CATALINA_BASE%\temp.
rem
rem   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
rem                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
rem
rem   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
rem                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
rem                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
rem
rem   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when any command
rem                   is executed.
rem                   Include here and not in CATALINA_OPTS all options, that
rem                   should be used by Tomcat and also by the stop process,
rem                   the version command etc.
rem                   Most options should go into CATALINA_OPTS.
rem
rem   JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS (Optional) Lists of of semi-colon separated directories
rem                   containing some jars in order to allow replacement of APIs
rem                   created outside of the JCP (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C).
rem                   It can also be used to update the XML parser implementation.
rem                   Defaults to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed.
rem
rem   JPDA_TRANSPORT  (Optional) JPDA transport used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. The default is "dt_socket".
rem
rem   JPDA_ADDRESS    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. The default is 8000.
rem
rem   JPDA_SUSPEND    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. Specifies whether JVM should suspend
rem                   execution immediately after startup. Default is "n".
rem
rem   JPDA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. If used, JPDA_TRANSPORT, JPDA_ADDRESS,
rem                   and JPDA_SUSPEND are ignored. Thus, all required jpda
rem                   options MUST be specified. The default is:
rem
rem                   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,
rem                       address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
rem
rem   LOGGING_CONFIG  (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging config file
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
rem
rem   LOGGING_MANAGER (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging manager
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
rem
rem   TITLE           (Optional) Specify the title of Tomcat window. The default
rem                   TITLE is Tomcat if it's not specified.
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set TITLE=Tomcat.Cluster#1.Server#1 [%DATE% %TIME%]
rem
rem
rem
rem $Id: catalina.bat 1344732 2012-05-31 14:08:02Z kkolinko $
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: My catalina.bat was slightly less friendly than this, but I did find a bit about setting the title and modified it to suite my needs, thanks for that.

Comment: @adarshr: Flawless answer. The custom title looks really cool.

Answer (score 6):

In **catalina.bat** make the following change:

```
:doStart
...
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=MY TOMCAT TITLE
```

where **MY TOMCAT TITLE** is the title that you want to give to the java window.

Comment: Thanks, this is (almost) exactly what I needed. I use a variation to display the current directory (I run many Tomcats on my machine) so I set the TITLE to %CD%

Comment: Nice, I like the idea of automatic title based on current dir

Comment: how to change color console tomcat?